# Function Not Called

Tags: c

I wrote a program in which a function is called which returns a 2-D array pointer and takes a 2-D array as an argument. But somehow while running the function is not called. I'm  not able to figure it out. Any Suggestions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
signed char** complement(signed char no_of_variables[20][20]);
int main(void)
{

  FILE *ptr_file;
  FILE *ptr_file1;
  FILE *ptr_file2;
  signed char **no_of_variables_or3;
  //signed char **no_of_variables_or2;

  signed char i, j, k, w;
  signed char no_of_variables[20][20], no_of_variables2[23][1000];
  //char no_of_sops[1];
  //char a = no_of_sops[0];

  //char value[a][10];
  ptr_file = fopen("part1.txt", "r+");
  if (!ptr_file)
    return 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    fgets(no_of_variables[i], 20, ptr_file);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < no_of_variables[1][0]; i++)
  {
    fgets(no_of_variables[i + 2], 20, ptr_file);
  }

  fclose(ptr_file);

  signed char var = 2 + (no_of_variables[1][0] - 48);
  for (i = 0; i < (var); i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
      no_of_variables[i][j] = no_of_variables[i][j] - 48;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 23; i++)
  {
    //for( j=0;j<1000;j++){
    //  outputarray[i][j] = " ";
    printf("val%d\n", no_of_variables[i][0]);
  }

  no_of_variables_or3 = complement(no_of_variables[20][20]);

  FILE *optr_file;
  optr_file = fopen("output_part1.txt", "r+");
  if (!optr_file)
    return 1;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    fputs(no_of_variables_or3[i], optr_file);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < no_of_variables_or3[1][0]; i++)
  {
    fputs(no_of_variables_or3[i + 2], optr_file);

  }
  fclose(optr_file);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The best suggestion would be - let us see your code..

Comment: If you are not able to find error by seeing your code then how could you expect us to find that without seeing it? o.O

Comment: Either post some code or figure it out yourself.

Comment: where's the definition of complement?, and why are you calling it with a scalar? and why are you assigning it to something that is never declared anywhere?

Comment: Where's the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
no_of_variables_or3 = complement(no_of_variables[20][20]);
```

to be:

```
no_of_variables_or3 = complement(no_of_variables);
```

The compiler should have pointed you to this by issuing a warning.

Comment: @steve i have declared no_of_variable_or3.

Comment: is there any mistake in assigning the value returned back?

Comment: What you show looks ok. If it makes sense depends on what happens inside of `complement()`.